# useEffect triggering before useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that is supposed to register every input (through useState) and constantly check if that is valid (through useEffect), but that console.log always seems to return a outdated check so I think it is first checking if it's valid and then registering the change.

```
//SAVING INPUTS
const [values, setValues] = useState({})

function handleChange(e) {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
}

//VALIDATING FORM
const [validation, setValidation] = useState({ emailValid: false })

useEffect(() => {
    handleEmail()
    console.log(validation)
}, [values])

function handleEmail() {
    const { email } = values
    const emailIsValid = /[\w]+@[\w]+.(com|br|net)/.test(email)

    setValidation({ ...validation, emailValid: emailIsValid })
}
```

> This is the form's input field:

```
<div className="inputbox">
    <label htmlFor="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" required onChange={e => handleChange(e)} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre code is fine. Because `console.log(validation)` runs before `setValidation({ ...validation, emailValid: emailIsValid })`.
updating the state is asynchronous https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Use another useEffect to display validation

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(validation)
}, [validation])
```